# Deploying a Symfony2 App onto Azure Web hosting

Tags: php, symfony, azure

what my aim here is to, upload my project that is basically a controller returning a twig template its as simple as that, i just cant figure out how to get it on the hosting.

I have been using symfony for a few months now, so still new to it all. and all the hosting/details stuff is new too me.

Whats throwing me off is my understanding of a hosting web/ folder
and how azures its wwwroot/

i used this website

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html

but i'm finding it rather difficult to follow it..

does anyone have any better sites with more clear steps on how to deploy? i've read a lot about a public_html folder but i've never heard/used it before

If someone could explain how the www.domain.com/web/app.php works that would help, i know that, that is the file that is called, but not too sure if i need to say call this file "app.php" or if its done kinda like the way a standard websites looks for 'index.php'

any kinda help or pointers would be much appreciated here as i'm kinda lost

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, we can build our project and test on local, then deploy on Azure Web Apps via Git or FTP tools.

Here is my test steps:

1. Build Symfony project on local, referring [Using the Symfony full-stack framework](http://symfony.com/download)
2. Login to Azure preview Portal, click **NEW**=> **Web+Mobile**=> **Marketplace**, in **Web Apps** section click **Web app + MySQL**, then click **create**.
3. When finishing creating Web app service, we can find MySQL connection string in **Settings**=>**Application settings**=>**Connection strings** click **show connection string**.
   [image]
4. then click **Set up continuous deployment** in Deployment section. Select **Local Git Repository** for the source. Then in **Essentials** section, we can find there added a Git URL. Copy it.
   [image]
5. In your local symfony project, make sure your Symfony repository has a `.gitignore` file at its root directory with at least the following contents:

   `/app/bootstrap.php.cache
   /app/cache/*
   /app/config/parameters.yml
   /app/logs/*
   !app/cache/.gitkeep
   !app/logs/.gitkeep
   /app/SymfonyRequirements.php
   /build/
   /vendor/
   /bin/
   /composer.phar
   /web/app_dev.php
   /web/bundles/
   /web/config.php`
6. run the following commands to init git repo and first-time push to Azure:
   `
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "initial commit"
   git remote add azure [URL for remote repository]
   git push azure master
7. Sign on Kudu console of your Azure web site, at `https://<your-website-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, run following commands:

   `cd site\wwwroot
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    php composer.phar install`

   [image]
   Now visit `http://<your-website-name>.azurewebsites.net/web/app.php` in browser, we should see the project.
8. Now we need to configure URL rewrite to remove `/web/app.php` pattern of the url. Add a file named `web.config` with the content shown in Deploying to [Microsoft Azure Website Cloud](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/azure-website.html) in the root directory which is `/site/wwwroot` on Azure. Click restart on Azure portal, now we can  visit the site at  `http://<your-website-name>.azurewebsites.net` .

By the way, for deploying a PHP-MySQL application on Azure Web Apps, we can get more information at [Create a PHP-MySQL web app in Azure App Service and deploy using Git](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/). And specifically [for Symfony project](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/azure-website.html), the Symfony guide is still useful, and we can ignore section Enabling the PHP intl Extension .

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful clear steps! cant thank you enough!! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the name of the "wwwroot" directory to "web", you have to change the configuration of symfony to use "wwwroot" instead.

Have a look at this [page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory)!

I think the easiest solution is the one with the symlink:

> Some shared hosts have a public_html web directory root. Renaming your web directory from web to public_html is one way to make your Symfony project work on your shared host. Another way is to deploy your application to a directory outside of your web root, delete your public_html directory, and then replace it with a symbolic link to the web in your project.